# Makefile doesn't use implicit rule on file

Tags: c++, makefile, c++14

I just wanted to write a quick Makefile for a small C++ project, but when I try to build, make says:

> No rule to make target "obj/main.o"

even though my implicit rule should cover that file. I have seen others who had forgotten a slash or something, but I dont't see the problem with this Makefile:

```
.PHONY: run, clean

SRCDIR:=./src
OBJDIR:=./obj
BINDIR:=./bin

CC:=gcc
CXX:=g++

SRC:=$(shell find -name *.cpp)
HXX:=$(shell find -name *.hpp)
OBJ:=$(subst src/,obj/,$(SRC:%.cpp=%.o))
EXE:=main

CXXFLAGS:=-std=c++14 -Wall

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    @echo $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $^ -o $(BINDIR)/$@

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.hpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I am using Raspberry Pi OS on my Raspberry Pi 3 b.

Comment: A guess but your rule is for `./obj/main.o` your dependency is `obj/main.o`

Comment: Sadly that's not it, if I change OBJDIR to just be obj it is the same, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of

> ```
> $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp $(SRCDIR)/%.hpp
> ```

you can only compile file having *both* a *cpp* and a *hpp*, but your main does not have header (e.g. you have a *src/main.cpp* but no *src/main.hpp*)

Example :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ find .
.
./bin
./src
./src/main.cpp
./Makefile
./obj
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ make
make: ***  Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible « obj/main.o », nécessaire pour « main ». Arrêt.
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ touch src/main.hpp
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ make
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o
./obj/main.o
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall obj/main.o -o ./bin/main
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $
```

(*Aucune règle pour fabriquer la cible ...* means *No rule to make target*)

---

Changing the line by

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.cpp
```

the compilation is done :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ find .
.generally
./bin
./src
./src/main.cpp
./Makefile
./obj
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ make
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall -c src/main.cpp -o obj/main.o
./obj/main.o
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall obj/main.o -o ./bin/main
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $
```

To add the dependency to the header is not enough to recompile when necessary when a source `#include` other header files which is often the case.

You can look at [makedepend](https://linux.die.net/man/1/makedepend), to install it under raspbian/debian/ubuntu : `apt-get install xutils-dev`

---

Note the link is done each time you do *make* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ find .
.
./bin
./bin/main
./src
./src/main.hpp
./src/main.cpp
./Makefile
./obj
./obj/main.o
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ make
./obj/main.o
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall obj/main.o -o ./bin/main
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $ make
./obj/main.o
g++ -std=c++14 -Wall obj/main.o -o ./bin/main
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp/p $
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an idea how to make all object files dependant on all headers or should I just look into dependencies?

Comment: if you make all object depending on all headers you will recompile for nothing, look at *makedepend* ( `apt-get install xutils-dev` for raspbian)

Comment: makedepend is _seriously_ old-school.  You can try here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ although your environment might not be worth it.  It's easy to have your objects depend on all headers, just add `$(HXX)` to your pattern rule.  If your project is not too big and you don't mind unnecessary recompiles, it's a lot simpler.

Comment: @MadScientist yes I know *makedepend* is old ... as me ^^ "*It's easy to have your objects depend on all headers...*" the interest of having a Makefile is to *not* recompile all, if you want to recompile all each time something moves just use a shell script without any consideration about the modification/creation date of the files

Comment: I don't disagree but some projects are just not big enough to need any amount of boilerplate to manage dependencies.  I've worked on useful projects that were small enough that they put most everything in one header. And note, a makefile is still an improvement over a shell script because it only recompiles when you change _header_ files.  It still saves you time when you're only modifying source files.